# Error Smarty - Fatal error: Uncaught exception

Tags: php, html, smarty

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template "C:\xampp\htdocs\eventos\libs\templates\teste.tpl" on line 9 "Ola! {$names}, bem vindo ao Smarty!" unknown tag "private_print_expression"' in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventos\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php:441 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\eventos\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php(263): Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->trigger_template_error('unknown tag "pr...', 9) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\eventos\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templateparser.php(2338): Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->compileTag('private_print_e...', Array, Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\eventos\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templateparser.php(2846): Smarty_Internal_Templateparser->yy_r28() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\eventos\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templateparser.php(2946): Smarty_Internal_Templateparser->yy_reduce(30) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\eventos\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_smartytemplatecompiler.php(51): Smart in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventos\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 441

my php code

```
<?php
include('includes/header.html');
include('conf/conf.php');
require_once(SMARTY_DIR.'Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty();

$smarty->template_dir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\eventos\libs\templates';
$smarty->compile_dir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\eventos\libs\templates_c';
$smarty->config_dir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\eventos\libs\configs';
$smarty->cache_dir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\eventos\libs\cache';

$smarty->assign('name','Ned');

$smarty->display('teste.tpl');
?>
```

and my smart code (teste.tpl)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
Ola! {$name}, bem vindo ao Smarty!
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$smarty->assign('name','Ned');
```

to

```
$smarty->assign('names','Ned');
```

Comment: What smarty version you use? and other information? use with prestashop? or?